# Center text in Highcharts' bubble chart's data labels

Tags: javascript, css, angular, highcharts

I am working with Angular 2 and [ng2-highcharts](https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts) library.

This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/jzawgwef/3/

**I want to center the text inside the bubble.**

I have tried to add style inside `dataLabel` attribute:

```js
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  style: {
    width: '150px',
    'text-align': 'center' // this does not work
  },
  format: '{point.name}'
}
```

I have noticed that the generated output has the style rule `text-align: center` but is positioned using two attributes (`x` and `y`):

```html
<g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-bubble-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker"
    transform="translate(64,46) scale(1 1)"
    opacity="1">
  <g class="highcharts-label highcharts-data-label highcharts-data-label-color-0 "
      style="text-align:center;"
      transform="translate(185,141)">
    <text x="5"
        y="16"
        style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;text-outline:1px contrast;fill:#000000;">
      <tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline"
          fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF"
          stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">
          Very long data label text I
      </tspan>
      <tspan dy="14" x="5" class="highcharts-text-outline"
          fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#FFFFFF"
          stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round">
          want to center
      </tspan>
      <tspan x="5" y="16">
        Very long data label text I
      </tspan>
      <tspan dy="14" x="5"> <!-- This x changes the span position -->
        want to center
      </tspan>
      <title>Very long data label text I want to center</title>
    </text>
  </g>
</g>
```

There is a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable [useHTML](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) for dataLabels:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
        width: '150px'
    },
    format: '{point.name}'
}
```

You can then target the label with CSS:

```
.highcharts-data-label span {
    text-align: center;
}
```